# Add support for Contextual Identities in Firefox AddOn - Request from background in same cookieStoreId

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I'm trying to add support for Contextual Identities in a FireFox Add-on.

In my background page Im doing XMLHttpRequest calls. This is not using the cookieStoreId of the current tab.

Is there a way to set the contextualIdentitie and/or cookieStoreId of the browser to the one of the calling tab?

Answer (score 0):

Got to a solution via this thread
https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/specify-context-container-ajax-or-fetch/29697/4

Thanks @mstanke